# Web Scraping: My first project and no idea where to start

Tags: python-3.x, excel, database, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have very little experience but a lot of persistence. One of my hobbies is football and I help in a local team. I'm a big fan of statistics and unfortunately the only way to collect data from the local football federation is by web scraping. I have seen python with beautifulsoup package can help but I cannot identify the tags as these I believe are on a table.

My goal is to automatically collect the information to build up a database with players, fixtures, teams, referees,... and build up stats such as how many times has player been on the starting line up, when are teams more likely to score a goal, when to receive a goal,...

I have two links for a reference.

The [first](http://fcf.cat/resultats/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-11/jornada-2) is for the general fixtures of a given group.

The [second](http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-11/1i/can-vidalet-cf-a/1i/sant-ildefons-ue-b) is the details with a match of any of a given match.

Any clues or where to start with the pattern would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mahdi_J thanks for the initial response. I have already started the approach:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-11/1i/sant-ildefons-ue-b/1i/lhospitalet-centre-esports-c", headers={'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0'})

c = r.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")
```

What I need is some support on where to start for the parsing. On the url I neeed to collect the players for both teams, the goals, bookings to save them to else where. What I'm having trouble is how to parse. I have very little skills and I need some starting point for the parsing.

Comment: Try learning regular expression. it teaches you how to dynamically search for patterns in a string. that will help you 100%. there are so many good tutorials in YouTube for re.

Answer (score 3):

you should first get into web-scraping using python native libraries like `requests` to kinda contact the page that you want. then depending on the page, you should use bs4 (Beautifulsoup) to find what you are looking for inside the page. Then what you wanna do is transform and refine that information into variables (list or dataframes based on your need) and finally save those variables into a dataset. here is an example code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup #assuming you already have bs4 installed

page = requests.get('www.DESTINATIONSITE.com/BLAHBLAH')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup_str = str(soup.text)
```

up to this point, you have the string values of the entire page at hand. now you wanna do some regular expression or any other python coding to seperate the information that you want from `soup_str` and store them in variable(s).

for the rest of the process, if you want to save that data, i suggest you look into libraries like pandas

Answer (score 1):

I have done some progress

## import libraries

import pandas as pd

import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

## send request

url = 'http://fcf.cat/acta/1920/futbol-11/infantil-primera-divisio/grup-11/1i/sant-ildefons-ue-b/1i/lhospitalet-centre-esports-c'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,'html.parser')

## read acta

acta_text = []
acta_text_element = soup.find_all(class_='acta-table')

for item in acta_text_element:
    acta_text.append(item.text)

when I print the items I get many \n